# Yeoman Angular Generator not configured properly for brackets.io

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, yeoman, adobe-brackets

I am looking for help in getting the Live Preview working in [brackets.io](http://brackets.io) using a Yeoman generated Angular seed application.

The directory structure for the Angular project has an `app` subdirectory in which the program code is included, which has the required entry point `index.html`.

This index.html refers to the `bower_components` folder as a relative address, and also has relative links to the `js` subdirectories under the `app` folder.

[image: Directory structure generated by Yeoman Angular]

I am using the Live Preview feature of brackets.io, and this fails to find both Angular and Bootstrap using the default relative paths.

I have used both the internal web browser, as well as an IIS application which I have set up (which runs fine by itself) and the same problem occurs in both when the Live Preview is started.

As a workaround, I have changed these to absolute paths but **I am looking for the possible reasons as to why the relative paths are not being found**.

This appears to be specific to the Live Preview of brackets.io rather than within the generated code.

Original generated code:

> ```
> <!-- build:js(.) scripts/vendor.js -->
> <!-- bower:js -->
> <script src="bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
> <script src="bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
> <script src="bower_components/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
> <script src="bower_components/angular-animate/angular-animate.js"></script>
> <script src="bower_components/angular-cookies/angular-cookies.js"></script>
> <script src="bower_components/angular-messages/angular-messages.js"></script>
> <script src="bower_components/angular-resource/angular-resource.js"></script>
> <script src="bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.js"></script>
> <script src="bower_components/angular-sanitize/angular-sanitize.js"></script>
> <script src="bower_components/angular-touch/angular-touch.js"></script>
> <!-- endbower -->
> <!-- endbuild -->
>
>     <!-- build:js({.tmp,app}) scripts/scripts.js -->
>     <script src="scripts/app.js"></script>
>     <script src="scripts/controllers/main.js"></script>
>     <script src="/.bowerrc"></script>
>     <!-- endbuild -->
> ```

My workaround:

> ```
> <!-- build:js(.) scripts/vendor.js -->
> <!-- bower:js -->
> <script src="/bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
> <script src="/bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
> <script src="/bower_components/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
> <script src="/bower_components/angular-animate/angular-animate.js"></script>
> <script src="/bower_components/angular-cookies/angular-cookies.js"></script>
> <script src="/bower_components/angular-messages/angular-messages.js"></script>
> <script src="/bower_components/angular-resource/angular-resource.js"></script>
> <script src="/bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.js"></script>
> <script src="/bower_components/angular-sanitize/angular-sanitize.js"></script>
> <script src="/bower_components/angular-touch/angular-touch.js"></script>
> <!-- endbower -->
> <!-- endbuild -->
>
>     <!-- build:js({.tmp,app}) scripts/scripts.js -->
>     <script src="/app/scripts/app.js"></script>
>     <script src="/app/scripts/controllers/main.js"></script>
>     <script src="/.bowerrc"></script>
>     <!-- endbuild -->
> ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing if you are using yeoman angular generator, then you will be running grunt "serve" task which will handle all tasks(including livereload) defined under 'serve' section of yr gruntfile. And yr Brackets has no role so far.

If you are not using grunt, and you are using bracket's livereload, then you have to do 2 tasks.

1.) Update yr .bowerrc as below

```
 {
   "directory": "app/bower_components"
 }
```

Now all yr bower dependencies will go to directory specified, here you want them 
to go inside "app" folder.

2.) Now you can just host yr app folder & yr browser will find all dependencies. 
    No need to change index.html

Note : Again Yeoman is independent and grunt file generated by "angular-generator" handles different tasks.
  Brackets has no role or dependencies here. **When you are doing "Live Preview" with brackets its only running yr index.html file and this way yr content outside app folder is not accessible**

Comment: Thanks @nitin. I have set up Grunt forbrackets and have run this and there are no errors. The bower_components are in the root and not under app in the generated code so this option did not work. After running Grunt I removed the relative links but it reverts backs to its behaviour and does not find the links. I do accept your position that this is not Brackets but rather part of the set up. I will keep experimenting to try to find the solution.

Comment: I found the problem. It seems that Grunt and the Live Preview are essentially doing the same thing and seem to be in conflict with each other. When i use grunt serve (as you pointed me to) the web site shows up in Chrome with dynamic changing as I edit. Thanks again.